# Elegant solutions to replacing multiple characters in a string

Tags: python

I'm scraping a Html report for people using licenses for a bespoke software, as a way to bulk email them asking to free up a license in times of need.

I split the string read from the html file into a list, separated by newlines, and `.split()` out everything else I don't need (like html formatting, pc name etc.)

The output from the file however looks like:

```
["foo.bar", 'test.name', "john.doe"] etc.
```

I added `@[companyname].com` to the end of each name, and converted the entire list to a string. Then, I come to my issue. I want to get rid of the unneeded text from the list. as shown below:

```
onlineUsers = str(userEmailAddress).replace(",",";").replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","")
```

I added the following browser popup with a mailto link at the bottom:

```
webbrowser.open_new("mailto:" + onlineUsers)
```

And everything works like a dream, however the chaining of `.replace()` really bugs me. I've looked around for more elegant solutions, but they end up being more clunky and it seems like using a sledgehammer on a nail.

Is there an elegant way to do multiple replaces simultaneously? 
Or, at least, is there a better way to format this?

Comment: Should be reasonable to implement a small function, which accepts a list of strings to replace (or pairs of strings if the target string shall be configurable). Then just iterate over the list and call replace for each argument on the intermediate value. Don't think there is anything more idiomatic.

Comment: To the OP K-Shelton: Please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145499/how-to-ask-best-practice-questions) questions on Meta and consider reformulating your question to allow for a less opinionated and more to-the-point answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, also read my comment on the original question.

As to still provide an answer, something I've used before is this:

```
for char in ['b\'', "\'", "\\n", '"', '[', ']', ',']: # Add any kind of char you would like to remove
    if char in targeted_variable_value:
        clean_output = targeted_variable_value.replace(char, "")
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I guess I accidently used a bit of a  buzzword which is fairly easy to misunderstand in my title, I totally agree with what you're saying. What I was looking for is something more elegant and robust than what I had already done. I'm still learning, so I'm taking everything on board with me as I go. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SB87 @K-Shelton How will this replace different characters with different ones such as the one OP posted in question i.e. `","` with `";"` and `"["` with `""`.

Comment: @SatishGarg I'm still using a .replace() for that. This deals with the bulk of the things I want to replace though. (i.e. "[" or " ' " with  " "). The point of my OP is that this is much cleaner than using 3 more instances of .replace() for what will be the same end value.

Comment: @SatishGarg plus 1 for your answer as it seems to be applicable to a wider range of replacements. I've also tested both solutions for speed and there appears to be only a negligible difference. I'd say, for ease of use and on simple string-variable replacements my answer will do, for slightly more complex replacements yours is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @SB87 Thanks. That's why i decided to answer as i couldn't find any answers related to multi-multi replacement otherwise would have flagged as `duplicate` :-)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid chaining explicitly, you can create a `dict()` of **text to be replaced as keys** and **text to be replaced with as values** t, something like this :

```
lst = ["blah[,].com", "gen@,]'com"]
rpl = {
    "," : ";",
    "[" : "",
    "]" : "",
    "'" : ""
}
lst1 = []
for lst_v in lst : 
    for k, v in rpl.items():
        lst_v = lst_v.replace(k, v)
    lst1.append(lst_v)
print lst1
```

This will result in :

```
['blah;.com', 'gen@;com']
```